# SSIS Execute Process Task hanging from SQL Server Job, no errors given

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a basic SSIS package that has an execute process task which runs a .exe sitting on our NAS/Share drive which produces a csv file and is read by later steps.

I can execute the SSIS package within BIDS and everything works flawlessly. When deploying to the server and running from job the SSIS package just hangs and stays in executing mode.

To verify we could run it from the server, I tried running the .exe from the command line from within the server and came across an error which was stopping the .exe running, turns out we needed a 64bit, windows server 2008 specific .exe which we have put together. Despite updating the .exe and being able to run it from the command line in the server now we are still suffering the same issue.

Any ideas, pointers, even potential research avenues would be greatly appreciated as I am relatively new to SSIS and am patiently trying to hack my way through it.

Cheers

Comment: Any error? Did You try to turn on the logging? Did You try to set the job to use the same credentials as yours (like executing from BIDS)?

Comment: Tools like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) may be useful.  Does the exe process hang or does it complete and exit?

Comment: Logging for every event has been turned on, no errors on that step and it claims that the step finishes successfully, however the SSIS package does not progress to the next step and the outputs from the .exe are not created which leaves it haning in the SQL Job. Have tried executing with different credentials and everything works great in BIDS, just not when running form a SQL Server Job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using your executable from a UNC path you will have to add it in the zone setting in Local intranet.

On your Internet Explorer, go to Security and select Local Intranet setting. Click on Sites and add your UNC path and click ok. The file:// protocol is added automatically.

This has nothing to do with SSIS, but everything to do with the zone settings in Internet Explorer.

This should help.

Comment: This one worked. When trying to execute from within BIDS on the server at the execute process task there would always be a pop up asking if you wanted to trust this publisher which I think was aprt of the problem. Everything works great